# How to count the frequency of some fixed values in each row and columns of two different pairs of rows of a matrix in R by using loop commands

Tags: r

I have a matrix,

`A=matrix(c(0,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,1),3,3)`.
`N= 3` rows and `n=3` rows.

I have some fixed values.

`Ro`= how many times 1 occurs in each row.

`R1= n-Ro` are the remaining values in each row.

`R11=(1,1)`

I want to check how many times this pair occurs in different columns of two rows. `Ro1=(0,1), (1,0), (1,2), (2,1)` I want to check how many times these fixed values occur in different columns of two rows. I want to do the same for other fixed values `Roo=(0,0), (2,2)` and also `Ro2=(0,2), (2,0)`.

I uploaded pictures and explanations in the following links.

[how to count the frequency of some fixed values in each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pluWq.jpg).

[some fixed values in different  columns of two rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdJV2.jpg).

[how to calculate this expression in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQimr.jpg)

Comment: The first two are easy, `Ro <- rowSums(A == 1)` and `R1 <- ncol(A) - Ro`, but the rest is not so clear. Do the rows/columns have to be adjacent. What do you expect the results to be for your example data?

Comment: thank you so much for your answers. I have upload the pictures. Kindly click on blue words. It will be helpful for you for understand. waiting for your kind reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: fixed values: Roo=(0,2) and (2,0). now we take first and second row. 
1st row:  0  1  2          
2nd row: 1  2  0 .    I want to check these fixed value (0,2) occur in first column or second column or in third column. the answer is yes once time in third column. so Roo is 1.    same as 
1st row:  0     1      2
3rd row: 2     0      1    . i want to check the fixed value is occur in first column or second column or third column. the answer is yes only once time in first column. so Roo= 1
Also for second row and third row.

Answer (score 0):

This may be close to what you want:

```
A <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1), 3, 3)
Ro <- rowSums(A == 1)
R1 <- ncol(A) - Ro
```

This is the first part of your question. Now to match patterns in pairs of rows.

```
pairs <- as.matrix(expand.grid(Row1=1:3, Row2=1:3))
pairs <- t(pairs[pairs[, 1] < pairs[, 2], ])
pairs
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# Row1    1    1    2
# Row2    2    3    3
```

The `pairs` matrix gives the rows in which we will search for matches, row 1 with 2, row 1 with 3, and row 2 with 3.

```
freqcount <- function(A, pairs, pattern) {
     sum(sapply(seq(dim(pairs)[2]), function(i) sum(apply(A[pairs[, i], ], 2,
           function(x) all(x==pattern)))))
}
```

The `freqcount()` function will take a matrix `A`, a `pairs` matrix, and a `pattern` which must be a 2x1 matrix, e.g. `rbind(1, 1)`. Now we need to create a set of patterns and search for them in the matrix:

```
Patts <- t(expand.grid(Row2=0:2, Row1=0:2))[2:1, ]
Freqs <- apply(Patts, 2, function(x) freqcount(A, pairs, pattern=x))
Results <- rbind(Patts, Freqs)
Results
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# Row1     0    0    0    1    1    1    2    2    2
# Row2     0    1    2    0    1    2    0    1    2
# Freqs    0    2    1    1    0    2    2    1    0
```

So there are 0 occurrences of the (0, 0) pattern, 2 of the (0, 1) pattern, 1 of the (0, 2) pattern, etc.